# download xml files from 3 different directory of a ftp server to a local system by using ssis

Tags: ssis, ftp, task

I am new to ssis and my question

There are 3 different locations of a ftp server(c:\temp1\,c:\temp2\,c:\temp3) and I have to check all the three locations and if any xml files exist then I have to download to my local working directory(c:\workingxml) in a specific time let's say  within 4 A.M. to 8 A.M. and after 8A.M.the 3 different locations files move to a single location in the ftp server(c:\allxmlfiles) by ftp server.

if my ssis package failed within this time (4 A.M. to 8 A.M. ) then I have to take files from the single location of ftp server(c:\allxmlfiles).

so how could I write in a ssis script task to get the xml files from different locations of a ftp server in different time.

waiting for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, e.g. are new files appearing continuously on the FTP server during that time, or do you only download once from each location? Personally, I've found the SSIS FTP task a bit limited, especially if you have multiple files to download at multiple times. I would say that SSIS is good for things that run once, not for things that run repeatedly over a longer period of time.

In this case, I would probably write a small script or program in my favourite language to handle the FTP work, and schedule it from Windows or MSSQL. Whenever you're sure that all the files are downloaded then you can start the SSIS package to do more work.